# How to give an object to an array, when two variables of the constructor are missing?

Tags: java

Shopping Cart Program: How is it possible to create a new object in an Array (in this case at `cart[0]`) if the `main` method gives the constructor 5 variables, but it has only 3 variables in the constructor. It is not allowed to change the `main` method.
I tried something but I think that won´t work.

```
public class ShoppingCart {

public Item[] cart;
int temporary;
public ShoppingCart() {

}

 public void addItem(Item toAdd) {



     if(toAdd instanceof Grocery) {

         if(toAdd.pid==1) {


             cart[0]=new Grocery(toAdd.pid, toAdd.signifier, toAdd.pricePerUnit, ((Grocery) toAdd).getExpiryDate(), ((Grocery) toAdd).getPacketCount()+Grocery.packetCount);


         }



         if(toAdd.pid==2) {
            ............
```

main-method

```
public class ShoppingMall {

public static void main(String[] args){

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Ihr digitaler Warenkorb:");

    boolean loop = true;
    int item = 0;
    String action = "";
    int pckg;
    float amount = 0.0f;



    ShoppingCart basket = new ShoppingCart();

    while (loop) {
        System.out.println("\nWelcher Artikel soll bearbeitet werden");
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        System.out.println("1 Butter");
        System.out.println("2 Milch");
        System.out.println("3 Draht");
        System.out.println("4 Fliesen");           
        System.out.println("\nSie haben den Einkauf abgeschlossen?\nWaehlen Sie zwischen: ");
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        System.out.println("5 Warenkorb ausgeben");
        System.out.println("0 Exit\n");
        System.out.print("Ihre Eingabe bitte: ");

        try{
            item = Integer.valueOf(input.readLine());


            if((item < 5) && (item > 0))
            {
                //System.out.println("\n------------------------------");
                do{
                    System.out.print("Waehlen Sie + fuer hinzufuegen oder - fuer entfernen. ");
                    action = input.readLine();
                }while(!action.equals("+") && !action.equals("-"));
            }

            //if(action.equals("+") || action.equals("-"))
            //{
                switch (item) {
                    case 1: {
                        System.out.print("Wieviele Packungen Butter ? ");
                        pckg = Integer.valueOf(input.readLine());
                        Grocery groc = new Grocery(1,"Butter",1.59f,20180618,pckg);
                        if(action.equals("+"))
                            basket.addItem(groc);
                        else
                            basket.removeItem(groc);
                        break;
                    .....................
```

Comment: just add one more constructor which accepts three vars

Comment: Your question is incomplet, firstly can you approve the post edit. Secondly can you provide us with a clear question ( add Item & Grocery class structure ) so that we can help you !

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to be able to pass 3 values to the Grocery constructor, even though it needs 5.

Try to overload the constructor with three parameters that make the rest of the values default and define a new function that will let you modify the data in a Grocery object, by identifying that object with a key. In your case, the key can be Grocery.pid

Hope this was helpful.